# What are the attributes of the lines my line connects with?

Tags: line, fields-attributes, arcgis-pro

I have a series of lines with different attributes and have used Generate Near Table, Summary Statistics and Join Field to add a column with the number of lines each line is near to.

(I have had to use 'Near' as the lines do not always intersect).

```
    FID | Attribute | Near Count | 
    1   | Red       | 2          |
    2   | Red       | 1          |
    3   | Blue      | 3          |
```

I want to find out how many times each line connects with a line with a specific attribute.

```
    FID | Attribute | Near Count | Near to Red Count | Near to Blue Count | 
    1   | Red       | 2          | 1                 | 1                  |
    2   | Red       | 1          | 1                 | 0                  |
    3   | Blue      | 3          | 0                 | 3                  |
```

How would I go about adding these columns to my data?